# multiple imputation for prediction

Tags: classification, predictive-models, multiple-imputation

I am doing some experimentation with multiple imputation (MI) for prediction, more specifically in the context of binary classification.

I'm doing this because there is not much to be found with regard to the application of MI for prediction.

I would like some pointers to actual research about this topic (multiple imputation in predictive modelling).

Until now, almost all research I've found is not about MI and prediction but rather about the imputation methods themselves.

I wonder why that is.

Just to show I did some effort: I did find https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.07398 which is about feature selection after MI, which is in the good direction.

Comment: Asking for data is off-topic here, but you could ask at OpenData.SE. However, your last two paragraphs would make for a reasonable question here. Do you want to cut out the data request and edit your question to be more specific (what precisely is "this topic"?)?

Comment: ok i'll edit my question, although I hoped to get an answer that points to datasets used in research

Comment: So MI is especially popular in inferential statistics, where one cares more about the actual parameter estimates rather than "only" the quality of the predictions. MI here offers mostly better estimates of the standard error of the parameters. Using single value imputation is usually pretty good at estimating the parameters so for predicitive modeling this is sufficient. I guess that is why the focus of MI is more methdological

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I agree that it is more critical when dealing with inference. I also understand the "... is usally pretty good..." argument. However, I feel there is a philosophical problem with single imputation (don't know if that is the right way to describe it), even in prediction, and that multiple imputation adresses that problem (i.e. the problem of uncertainty). I did some (very limited, hence my question) experimenting with MI vs single imputation and it seemed to give better results (indeed not much, and to be honest: depending on the metric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, the (or at least one) right way to do this is clear (see e.g. [this question & answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517400/machine-learning-on-mice-imputed-data/542179#542179)), but this is also time-consuming, which I assume is why it's usually not done: Do multiple imputation, build model separately on each of the multiple imputations (of course being careful to [impute after training-validation-test-splitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608120/proper-imputation-of-missing-values-for-machine-learning/608126#608126)), if new data has no missing data then the overall prediction is the average of the predictions from each of these models (e.g. see [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605474/can-missing-data-imputations-outperform-default-handling-for-lightgbm/605485#605485) here). If the new data has missing values, then you need ideally should impute them coherently. I.e. create as many multiple imputations and use the implicit parameter values as used in the original multiple imputation for each imputation - that's easiest, if you did your multiple imputation explicitly with a Bayesian model fit using MCMC, a bit less easy for some imputation packages that abstract this away (and don't offer this option - which I think illustrates that mostly people building tools for multiple imputation think of inference on a fixed dataset, rather than about prediction).

Of course, it's not necessary to fit models separately for each imputation, although that's a common approach see e.g. the discussion in [BDA3](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/BDA3.pdf) starting from page 449 (esp. from 452 onwards, see also Zhou, X. and Reiter, J.P., 2010. [A note on Bayesian inference after multiple imputation](https://doi.org/10.1198/tast.2010.09109). The American Statistician, 64(2), pp.159-163.). E.g. in Bayesian MCMC samplers, there's approaches that jointly look at the likelihood over all imputations. Alternatively, I'd guess you could do things like picking a different imputation randomly for each tree (or even for each node split) in tree-based algorithms (like random forest or gradient boosted decision trees), but I've never seen that implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, these are helpful! Regarding the way to do it, I am doing it as alternative 3 in the post you refer to describes it, respecting the train/test splits. I didn't consider the potential problems regarding RF type algorithms with that alternative. On the other hand, as long as I am correctly using CV it should be ok, no?

Comment: My intuition on alternative 3 is that it's "not right" in the sense that you'll do worse on new data than if you did it "correctly". I'm speculating that there's 2 "problems": 1) not capturing the correlation of imputed values within each imputation (by mixing across imputed datasets), 2) ignoring that records are from the same subject (esp. problematic if you subsample records). But, you are right that as long as you do your CV correctly, you will not mislead yourself with respect to how well you are performing by doing things this way (you may just perform worse than you could have).